# Adding one day to timestamp using gwt bootstrap in client side

Tags: gwt, datetime, gwt-bootstrap

i have a GWT bootstrap dateTimeBox and i want to add one day to current time stamp i,e i wanna show default date to tomorrow in client side.
tried using calendar instance , but it gives compilation error .
Plz help how can i achieve this on client side without making a server call.

Answer (score 1):

To a add a day to current date in GWT you have to use the `CalendarUtil` class:

```
Date now = new Date();
CalendarUtil.addDaysToDate(now, 1); // change for the number of days, use negatives to subtract
```

Hope it helps.